# How to pass a list of strings

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

Using play framework 2.0 in Java mode and I want to pass a list of strings to a Controller using the URL parameters.

Given a URL such as:

```
http://localhost:9000/echo?messages=hello&messages=world
```

I want to call my Controller method:

```
public static Result echo(List<String> messages){
    return ok("Size: " + messages.size());
}
```

My routes file looks like this:

```
GET      /echo             controllers.Application.echo(messages: List[String])
```

But it doesn't work. I get errors claiming there is no QueryString binder for List[String]. This doesn't seem right to me as this was pretty standard functionality in the previous version. Does anybody know how I can pass a list of strings to the controller using a Java project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For now you can retrieve them from the query string:

```java
public static Result echo(){
    String[] messages = request().queryString().get("messages");
    return ok("Size: " + messages.length);
}
```

**Update:** A list binder [has been added](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/e549bf0ce1e908673c79537bf982fac8cef00a3e/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Binders.scala#L242), so you can just write the following:

```scala
public static Result echo(List<String> messages) {
  return ok("Size:" + messages.size());
}
```

Be sure your route definition looks like the following:

```
GET   /echo      controllers.Application.echo(messages: java.util.List[String])
```